# How do i fix "Error: could not find function "tokens"" in R (in RStudio)?

Tags: r, quanteda

While learning R, I am asked to use the package "quanteda" and apply the function "tokens". Unfortunately, when I try to do so, I get the message

```
Error: could not find function "tokens".
```

But I can use, for example, "tokenize".

My code is:

```
  train.tokens <- tokens(train$Text, what = "word", remove_numbers = TRUE, 
                  remove_punct = TRUE,remove_symbols = TRUE, remove_hyphens = TRUE).
```

As a side note, when I try to automatically update the quanteda package, it says that I have the 0.9.8.3 version and that the newest available is 0.9.8.5. After it gets updated, nothing happens.

Thank you!

Comment: did you install the "quanteda" package? if so, did you open it? with: `library(quanteda)`

Comment: `quanteda::tokens(....`

Comment: @p130ter Yes, I have it installed and loaded.

Comment: @PKumar If I replace tokens with quanteda::tokens(... the following message is printed "Error: 'tokens' is not an exported object from 'namespace:quanteda'".

Comment: Also I don't know if it is relevant or not but when I open help(package="quanteda") there is no "token" help page under the letter T.

Comment: Supply your `sessionInfo()`. It look like you just have an outdated package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you have a current version of **quanteda** and the packages that it imports.  Then this will work fine:

```
> quanteda::tokens("This is a test")
tokens from 1 document.
text1 :
[1] "This" "is"   "a"    "test"

> packageVersion("quanteda")
[1] ‘0.99.22’
```